# One Way Relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to find one way relationships in my table mysql table 'friends'

```
Name    Friend
John    Mary
Krish   Paula
Debbie  John
Paula   Krish
Mary    John
```

I want to list all pairs (A - B) for which no pair (B - A) can be found.
Example: The query should select row 4 (Debbie - John) since (John - Debbie) does not exist.

Comment: What code have you tried so far, and what does it do?

Comment: "self joins" will allow you to do that

Comment: So you want to list all pairs A - B for which no pair B - A can be found?

Comment: @icedwater: have not tried anything so far as I am clueless how to do this

Comment: @mnagel: Can you please give an example

Comment: @SantoshPillai http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/ does something very similar. try it out and report back with some code of yours, even if it is broken, that's much better than no code

Comment: @mnagel: had googled and am reading exactly the same page :)

Comment: @mnagel a self (anti) join would work yes. But it's not suited for novices I think. `NOT EXISTS` queries usually come easier for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use also use **[greatest() and least()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)**

```
Select 
greatest(Name,Friend),least(Name,Friend)
from Friends
group by greatest(Name,Friend),least(Name,Friend)
having count(1)=1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68b64/13)**

Comment: Correct. I would use `NOT EXISTS` subquery but this query (the only one among the many wrong answers) returns what is wanted.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select f1.* from Friends as f1
left join Friends as f2 on f1.Name = f2.Friend and f1.Friend = f2.Name
where f2.Name is null
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59469/4)

Comment: This will not show what has been asked.

Comment: @ypercube OP wants ***The query should select row 4 (Debbie - John) since (John - Debbie) does not exist.*** and Janne Matikainen has written the same query.

Comment: @Luv See this [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09520/1) and tell me why no row is returned.

Comment: @ypercube agree. In that case please refer my answer.

Comment: Edited my answer to work with the data provided by @ybercube

Comment: Yes, correct now. +1. Please edit to `SELECT f1.*` (no need to show the Nulls from the `f2` table)

Comment: @Luv This answer was only missing the second condition (`and f1.Friend = f2.Name`) but had the `IS NULL` check from the beginning (which Salil's has not.)

Comment: Thanks everyone :) Both answers work

Answer (score 1):

It's the query which solve your problem.

```
select * from friends where name not in (select a.name from friends a, friends b where a.friend=b.name and a.name=b.friend);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select Name, Friend from Friends as f1
left join Friends as f2 on f1.Name = f2.Friend AND f1.Friend = f2.Name
```

Comment: You need a `WHERE f2.Name IS NULL` check. And aliases on table names in the `SELECT`.